# Reading updated fixture file in Cypress

Tags: cypress, fixtures

I am trying to run a test case in which a fixture file is updated. I am then using this file and uploading it somewhere. The problem is that during the test run, Cypress caches the fixture files so even if the file is updated, cypress-file-upload uses the cached version of the file. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can adapt the example shown under [Working with raw file contents](https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload#working-with-raw-file-contents), and use `cy.readFile()` to bypass the caching problem with `cy.fixture()`.

```js
cy.readFile('./cypress/fixtures/my-file.json')
  .then(fileContent => {
    cy.get('[data-cy="file-input"]').attachFile({
      fileContent,
      filePath: './cypress/fixtures/my-file.json',
      encoding: 'utf-8',
      lastModified: new Date().getTime()
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with clearing the cypress-file-upload cache as well and the solution I found is reloading the page after each upload. For example:

```
cy.get('[data-qa="inputFile_image"]')
   .attachFile(image1.url)
cy.wait(4000)
cy.get('[data-qa="saveButton"]')
    .click()
cy.get('[data-qa="successNotification"]')
   .should('be.visible')
cy.reload()
cy.get('[data-qa="image1"]')
   .should('be.visible')
cy.get('[data-qa="inputFile_image"]')
    .attachFile(image2.url)
cy.wait(4000)
cy.get('[data-qa="saveButton"]')
    .click()
cy.get('[data-qa="successNotification"]')
    .should('be.visible')
cy.reload()
```

Comment: Are image1.url and image2.url pointing to the same file?

Comment: Not the same file, but reloading seems to clear the cache so thats why I Think It might help

Comment: Ok, well done - if you tweaked it to show the same file used (and modified the file before reload), it would be more meaningful.

Comment: The question is a bit light on example code, but I guess you'd also need to test the content of the uploaded file?

Comment: Testing the uploaded file and asserting it before the second upload seems reasonable way to write the test, but haven``t done such tasks so I cant help with ideas for that

Comment: @NankerPhelge is right. You are pointing to 2 different files so it wouldn't really help me in my case, would it?

Comment: Even he suggested that you should adapt your code. Since you didn`t share any code sample I shared mine that works for me in that situation. The second file can be the same since it is just a string to point to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import example from '../fixtures/example.json'

it('accessing fixture file array', () => {
    cy.fixture('example').then((userdata) => {
        userdata.forEach(function(item){
            cy.log('UserName: ' + item.username);
            cy.log('Password: ' + item.password);
            cy.log('Body: ' + item.body);
          });
      })
});
```

example.json:

```
[ {
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "admin",
  "body": "Fixtures data 1"
},
{
  "username": "test",
  "password": "test",
  "body": "Fixtures data 2"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `cy.readFile()` instead of `cy.fixture()`
the syntax needs to be adapted as follows:  
`cy.fixture('generated/${fileName}')` 
=> `cy.readFile('./cypress/fixtures/generated/${fileName}')`